# checking the status of command executed successfully

Tags: powershell

Sorry I am a newbie in PowerShell. I am running a script which executes some commands to copy files from a system.. Is there a way to capture the status of the command whether it completed successfully before moving to the next command?

For example:

```
$scp_cmd = "scp.exe -a root@192.168.1.1:/files/repo1 /repo1"
$rsync_cmd = "rsync.exe -tvP root@192.168.1.2:/files/repo2 /repo2"
Invoke-Expression $scp_cmd

# How do we check whether the command completed successfully?

Invoke-Expression $rsync_cmd

# How do we check whether the command completed successfully?
```

Comment: you should use try {Invoke-Expression $scp_cmd} ,example would be :try { something }
catch { "Error occured" }
if (!$error) {
"No Error Occured"
}

Comment: Thanks Niklas. I was going through exit codes, is this possible using PowerShell exit codes? For example- when the command is executed, would PowerShell know if the command returned an specific code?

Comment: not sure exactly want you mean, you can use exit.(0) in the code to end the script with 0 as exit code, but i don't know about if the command it self is able to exit with an "errorcode" other then 0 or 1 depending on error or not, you could try something i used in another script once:

$install = Start-Process -FilePath "CitrixReceiver.exe"

$result = $install.Exitcode

you could try calling the invoke-expression with $install in this example. it might only work for start-process, i'm not sure

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`$LASTEXITCODE` automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx). It works both with `Invoke-Expression` and the `&` call operator:

```
$rsync_cmd = "rsync.exe -tvP root@192.168.1.2:/files/repo2 /repo2"
Invoke-Expression $rsync_cmd

if($LASTEXITCODE)
{
    # exit code from rsync was not 0
}
```